# Dynamically sorting specific JSON nodes and returning in PHP function

Tags: php, json, laravel, sorting

I'm trying to sort the a specific node inside a json object and return it in a PHP function that looks like this.

```
{
    "2007":{
        "number-xx" : "5",
        "number-aa" : "30",
        "number-ef" : "2",
        "number-sa" : "-10",
        "number-ab" : "28",
    },
    "2008":{
        "number-xx" : "-1",
        "number-aa" : "0.5",
        "number-ef" : "23",
        "number-sa" : "55",
        "number-ab" : "43",    
    }
}
```

I want sort to each node under the "year" descending order and return it back in a function

```
{
   "number-xx" : "-1",
   "number-aa" : "0.5",
   "number-ef" : "23",
   "number-sa" : "55",
   "number-ab" : "43",    
}
```

PHP code to return the json

```
private function buildQuilt($fund_type){
    $path = storage_path() . "/data.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true); 

    //Do sort here
    foreach($json as $key => &$arr) {
       natsort($arr);
       $arr = array_reverse($arr);
    }//Seems to be breaking full object?

    return $json;
}
```

I want to return the entire data.json object sorted but my solution above seems to only return on year node.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting this?

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/767033)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$json='{
    "2007":{
        "number-xx" : "5",
        "number-aa" : "30",
        "number-ef" : "2",
        "number-sa" : "-10",
        "number-ab" : "28"
    },
    "2008":{
        "number-xx" : "-1",
        "number-aa" : "0.5",
        "number-ef" : "23",
        "number-sa" : "55",
        "number-ab" : "43"  
    }
}';
$data=json_decode($json,true);
$result=array();
foreach($data as $key=>$nodeData)
{
    asort($nodeData);
    $result[$key]=  $nodeData;
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [2007] => Array
        (
            [number-sa] => -10
            [number-ef] => 2
            [number-xx] => 5
            [number-ab] => 28
            [number-aa] => 30
        )

    [2008] => Array
        (
            [number-xx] => -1
            [number-aa] => 0.5
            [number-ef] => 23
            [number-ab] => 43
            [number-sa] => 55
        )

)
```

Comment: no I only want the node inside the years to be sorted. Also your example only sorts the first node.

Comment: on which bases you want to sort , on the basis of keys or values?

Comment: values only and only the nodes inside the year and NOT the year node itself. Hope that made sense!

Comment: @BaconJuice I have updated my post, Can you please check?

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the year is still flipped from 2007 being first to 2008 being first in your output. I basically don't want the years to switch only the values inside the year to change.

Comment: @BaconJuice i have updated my post again. check it once

Answer (score 1):

you may simply use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) with this :

```
private function buildQuilt($fund_type)
{
    $path = storage_path() . "/data.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true); 

    return array_map(function ($v) {
        natsort($v);
        return $v;
    }, $json);
}
```

this will output:

```
Array (
    [2007] => Array (
        [number-sa] => -10
        [number-ef] => 2
        [number-xx] => 5
        [number-ab] => 28
        [number-aa] => 30
    )
    [2008] => Array (
        [number-xx] => -1
        [number-aa] => 0.5
        [number-ef] => 23
        [number-ab] => 43
        [number-sa] => 55
    )
)
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/NHh7p

and if you want to reverse the order of your years keys , https://3v4l.org/YX3Ju

---

### Update

> I want sort to each node under the "year" descending order and return
>   it back in a function

to sort your 2-D array descending, you may use `rsort` instead :

```
private function buildQuilt($fund_type)
{
    $path = storage_path() . "/data.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true); 

    return array_map(function ($v) {
        rsort($v);
        return $v;
    }, $json);
}
```

this will output :

```
Array
(
    [2007] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 28
            [2] => 5
            [3] => 2
            [4] => -10
        )

    [2008] => Array
        (
            [0] => 55
            [1] => 43
            [2] => 23
            [3] => 0.5
            [4] => -1
        )

)
```